# (Java) How does sorting an array like this work?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-sort-a-random-number-array-in-java

Using the algorithm given in the above tutorial, how does the sorting logic work?
I tried manually coming up with each iteration:

i = 0    54, 63, 14, 78, 2, 3

i = 1    54, 14, 63, 78, 2, 3

i = 2    54, 14, 63, 78, 2, 3

i = 3    54, 14, 63, 2, 78, 3

i=4      54, 14, 63, 2, 3, 78

i = 5     ?

I cannot figure out what it would do at i=5, or how it would sort any further to get the correct result.

Comment: You could log the contents of the array after each swap, or step through the program with the debugger.

Comment: Becasue there are two `for` loops (i and j), it works properly. You only considered first loop - i.

Comment: I looks like last array isn't setted up. Show your code.. Do you generate all arrays in this same time?

Comment: "i" will not move to next until "j" reaches the end of the second loop
so your listing above is not correct, "i" will remain 0 until "j" loop is completed is (j<myArray.length)
in other words, you will need to compare 54 with all entries starting at (i+1)

Answer (score 0):

You never reach `i = 5`. The `for` loop is defined as follows: `for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)`. Since the size of your array is `6`, the maximum value of `i` will be `4`. Maybe the code below helps you to better understand the algorithm:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Input (unsorted) array */
        int[] myArray = new int[] { 3, 2, 1 };
        sort(myArray);

        System.out.println("Sorted my array. Now sorting your array!");

        /* Your array */
        int[] yourArray = new int[] { 54, 63, 14, 78, 2, 3 };
        sort(yourArray);
    }

    public static int[] sort(int[] array) {
        int size = array.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
                if (array[i] > array[j]) {
                    array = swapIntegers(array, i, j);
                }
                printCurrentState(array, i, j);
            }
        }

        return array;
    }

    /**
     * Swaps the integers at the specified indices. Changes the array, no copy created!
     * 
     * @param array
     *            Desired input array.
     * @param index1
     *            First index.
     * @param index2
     *            Second index.
     * @return
     *         Returns the input array, but the integers at the specified indices are swapped.
     */
    public static int[] swapIntegers(int[] array, int index1, int index2) {
        int temp = array[index1];
        array[index1] = array[index2];
        array[index2] = temp;

        return array;
    }

    /**
     * Small helper method to print the current state.
     */
    private static void printCurrentState(int[] array, int i, int j) {
        String txt = "";
        txt += "i=" + i + "\t";
        txt += "j=" + j + "\t";
        txt += Arrays.toString(array);

        System.out.println(txt);
    }
}
```

The output to the console will be:

```
i=0 j=1 [2, 3, 1]
i=0 j=2 [1, 3, 2]
i=1 j=2 [1, 2, 3]
Sorted my array. Now sorting your array!
i=0 j=1 [54, 63, 14, 78, 2, 3]
i=0 j=2 [14, 63, 54, 78, 2, 3]
i=0 j=3 [14, 63, 54, 78, 2, 3]
i=0 j=4 [2, 63, 54, 78, 14, 3]
i=0 j=5 [2, 63, 54, 78, 14, 3]
i=1 j=2 [2, 54, 63, 78, 14, 3]
i=1 j=3 [2, 54, 63, 78, 14, 3]
i=1 j=4 [2, 14, 63, 78, 54, 3]
i=1 j=5 [2, 3, 63, 78, 54, 14]
i=2 j=3 [2, 3, 63, 78, 54, 14]
i=2 j=4 [2, 3, 54, 78, 63, 14]
i=2 j=5 [2, 3, 14, 78, 63, 54]
i=3 j=4 [2, 3, 14, 63, 78, 54]
i=3 j=5 [2, 3, 14, 54, 78, 63]
i=4 j=5 [2, 3, 14, 54, 63, 78]
```

In a previous answer by yourself, you mentioned *bubble sort*. If you are interested in *bubble sort* - like operations, I highly recommend you to take a look into the [Heap Data Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) and how new elements are inserted into it.